# Valor de variável perdido ( JavaScript )

Tags: javascript, node.js

Tenho essa classe, mas sempre que instancio, e acesso o valor de `fb_firstName`está 'undefined'. O que estou fazendo errado?

dentro do metodo set, `setFb_firstName(firstName)` o valor esta correto, mas na hora de retornar com `getFb_firstName()` nao tem valor.

```
  function User(sender) {
        var fb_firstName; 


        FB.api('/' + sender, 'get', {access_token: token.getPage_acess_token()}, function (response) {
            setFb_firstName(response.first_name);
        });
        function setFb_firstName(firstName) {
            fb_firstName = firstName;
        }
        ;

        this.getFb_firstName = function () {
            return fb_firstName;
        };
    }
```

Comment: tava com esse mesmo problema aqui, resolvi o meu de outra forma porque era outra coisa, mas vi essa solução aqui:
(http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp), tá em ingles
mas pra simplificar, aonde tem `var fb_firstname` declare como `fb_firstName = '';`que deve funcionar

Comment: Não funcionou ainda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa passar uma função de callback para ser executada ao fim da requisição, caso contrário você terá problemas em atribuir valores assincronamente.

Veja um exemplo:

```
var User = function() {
    var username;
    return {
        init: function(callback) {
            FB.init(... , function(response) {
                username = response. username;
                callback();
            });
        },
        getUsername: function() {
            return username;
        }
    }
};

var user = new User(),
    username;
user.init(function() {
    username = user.getUsername();
});
```

Comment: js é do capiroto